# How to use mongoexport command with ssl?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.6, mongodb-4.0

I am trying to export collection data from (SSL MongoDB 4.x), for this I am running below command on linux terminal.
Earlier I used mongoexport command in Linux terminal without SSL which works properly for (MongoDB without SSL).

```
sudo mongoexport --verbose=1 --host X.X.X.X:27018 --ssl --sslCAFile "certificate.pem"  -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase XYZ_Database --collection XYZ_Collection --out Output.csv
```

### Error

```
2020-01-28T15:15:03.266+0000    could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
current topology: Type: Single
Servers:
Addr: X.X.X.X:27018, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection(X.X.X.X:27018[-121]) connection is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`--sslCAFile`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-sslcafile) argument, this is to specify the Certificate Authority file to be used against the server's certificate.

I think you might need to use [`--sslPEMKeyFile`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-sslpemkeyfile) instead of `--sslCAFile`.
Better yet, you might need to specify them both if you are using self-signed certificates with a custom Certificate Authority.